# ASP.NET does not attempt to open web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I am trying to get my .aspx page to read from its web.config file.  Code that works on other servers does not work as expected on one particular server (all machines involved are W2K3 R2 SP2).

A snippet of the .aspx is

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
     <asp:Label runat="server" Text="" ID="lblTime" /><br />
    Value of myConfigTest is '<asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" Text=""/>'
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The code is here:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Configuration;

namespace configTestWeb
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblTime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            string value = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConfigTest"];
            lblValue.Text = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And my web.config file is set thusly:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="myConfigTest" value="This is a test"/>
    </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

In an attempt to troubleshoot I setup ProcMon to filter on web.config and hit the page from a browser.  The output is

1:06:04 PM
Value of myConfigTest is ''

But the really strange thing is that ProcMon never reports an attempt to access the file!  If I right-click on the virtual directory in IIS and select Properties | ASP.NET | Edit Configuration I can see web.config being accessed with ~65 entries in ProcMon, and the appSetting is reported correctly in the ASP.NET Configuration Settings dialog.

I believe I've ruled out ACL's as an issue by
 
a) Setting the entire directory tree that the .aspx and web.config are in to Everyone | Full Permissions 
b) ProcMon would report failed attempts to open the file if permissions were the issue

In desperation I uninstalled / reinstalled ASP.NET 4.0.

It may be noteworthy that reading configuration from an .exe works perfectly on that server using

```
string value = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key];
```

This issue appears across multiple virtual directories.

So my question is, what might be preventing this one server from being able to read web.config files?

Comment: Haven't tried this - but I think `web.config` is read when the web app process starts (`aspnet_wp.exe` in 2k3/IIS6 I think), and then is cached by the application, so you won't see ProcMon accessing it after that. To verify: kill the web app process and reload browser to force it to restart.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary: good call, the .config file gets read when the application starts.  I can see my file being read, but I still don't get the expected value from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than going to trouble of using ProcMon try doing a simpler test: Edit web.config file to enable the trace feature, then access website and see if it shows the request trace.

Add this to your `web.config` inside of `system.web` node:

```
<trace
    enabled="true"
    requestLimit="10"
    pageOutput="false"
    traceMode="SortByTime"
    localOnly="false"
/>
```

By default changes to `web.config` (when file is saved/written to disk) will restart the ASP.NET application pool. These options can be changed, however, so if you do not see a change in your web app behavior after modifying `web.config` you can also try to stop and restart the service, or trigger an app pool recycle by using task manager to kill the `aspnet_wp.exe` process (I think this is what it is called in 2k3, if not try `w3wp.exe` instead), then make another request (refresh browser) to the web app and it IIS should start the app pool for ya.

If the changes (toggling between trace `enabled=true` and `enabled=false`) are not visible after saving `web.config`, but ARE visible after forcing stop/restart, then your IIS on that box may not have the option to restart app pool when configuration changes (don't have 2k3 in front of me, but in IIS 7 it is under Application Pools > Advanced Options > Recycling > "Disable Recyling for Configuration Changes" -- it is one of those annoying double-negative options, so "false" means recycle after config changes, and "true" means don't).

**Update:**
Dang, looks like IIS6 doesn't have that "for Configuration changes" option in the Recycling tab of the App pool properties sheet. Sorry, not sure where this setting is stored, doesn't appear to be in `machine.config` or `web.config` tho, so probably whatever IIS uses internally for the metabase stuff (registry maybe?)

If you try the trick for toggling trace and you don't see any effects, did you verify you are editing the correct `web.config` file?

Comment: I added the above to my web.config and cycled the w3wp.exe and got the same result with no trace. This dovetails with something I saw earlier in my investigation: adding <customErrors mode="Off" /> to system.web did NOT let me see detailed error info from a remote client. It feels like even the framework isn't reading the web.config file.
I'm editing the web.config in the same directory as the .aspx, which is in the root of the application.

Comment: I was gonna say another test is to put some bogus attributes in one of the nodes because the asp.net will throw a validation exception when app starts and reads the file. But yeah, sounds like you're either not editing the file you think you are, or there is some other issue I am not familiar with. Did you try creating a new virtual directory/application that points to the same folder?

Comment: I hadn't tried the new VD, just did, no help. As for editing the wrong file, I created a new directory, copied in the .aspx and .config files and bin directory, then right-clicked web.config and selected Edit.  Can't imagine getting that one wrong...Sigh.